# Select into multiple varibales with MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to write a stored procedure using mysql.

In the repeat loop showing below, if I use something as:

```
 SET VDATEI=(SELECT A.DATEI FROM STAFF_CONVENIOS A WHERE 
   A.CONV_ID=CONVE AND A.STAFF_ID=MED LIMIT 1);
```

the stored procedure works well and I get a result set.

But, I need select into multiple variables. Something as:

```
SELECT 
    A.DATEI, A.DIAI, A.HORAI  
INTO 
    VDATEI, VDIAI, VHORAI 
FROM
    STAFF_CONVENIOS A 
WHERE 
    A.CONV_ID = CONVE AND A.STAFF_ID = MED 
LIMIT 1;
```

In this case my stored procedure is broken I get no result set.

How to use select into to multiple variables into stored procedure with temporary tables?

My stored procedure is similar to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P_GETHORARIOS(
    IN `MED` BIGINT,
    IN `DATAREF` DATE,
    IN `ESPEC` BIGINT,
    IN `CONVE` BIGINT
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE BDONE,BTEMP, BOCUP INT;
  DECLARE DIA;
  DECLARE VDIA,OK TINYINT;  
  DECLARE VDURACAO TINYINT;
  DECLARE VDATEI DATE;
  DECLARE VDIAI TINYINT;
  DECLARE VHORAI TIME; 
  DECLARE VHORA, VHORAI,VHORAF TIME;

  DECLARE CURS CURSOR FOR  SELECT DIA,COALESCE(A.DURACAO,30) AS DURACAO, A.HINI   FROM STAFF_ESCALA A  
    WHERE A.DIA=DIA;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET BDONE = 1;

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TBLRESULTS;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TBLRESULTS  (
    DATA_AG DATE,
    DIA TINYINT,
    HORA TIME  );

  SET DIA=DAYOFWEEK(DATAREF);
  OPEN CURS;

  SET BDONE = 0;
  REPEAT
      SET OK=TRUE;
      FETCH CURS INTO VDIA,VDURACAO,VHORAI;

      -- SET VDATEI=(SELECT A.DATEI FROM STAFF_CONVENIOS A WHERE A.CONV_ID=CONVE AND A.STAFF_ID=MED LIMIT 1);
      SELECT A.DATEI, A.DIAI,A.HORAI  INTO VDATEI, VDIAI,VHORAI FROM STAFF_CONVENIOS A WHERE A.CONV_ID=CONVE AND A.STAFF_ID=MED LIMIT 1;
      SET BTEMP=IF(VDATEI IS NULL,TRUE,FALSE);
      SET OK=OK AND BTEMP ;
      IF (OK) THEN
            INSERT INTO TBLRESULTS VALUES (DATAREF,VDIA,VHORA);
      ELSE INSERT INTO TBLRESULTS VALUES (VDATEI,VDIAI,VHORAI);
    END IF;
  UNTIL BDONE END REPEAT;

  CLOSE CURS;

  SELECT A.* FROM TBLRESULTS;

END
```

I have posted a sample of my problem. Here is the real stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`SYSDBA`@`%` PROCEDURE `P_GETHORARIOS`(
    IN `MED` BIGINT,
    IN `DATAREF` DATE,
    IN `ESPEC` BIGINT,
    IN `CONVE` BIGINT
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
  DECLARE BDONE INT;
  DECLARE BTEMP TINYINT;
  DECLARE BOCUP TINYINT;
  DECLARE DIA BIGINT;
  DECLARE VDIA TINYINT;  
  DECLARE VDURACAO TINYINT;  
  DECLARE VHORA, VHORAI,VHORAF TIME;
  DECLARE VMED_ID BIGINT;
  DECLARE VESPEC_ID BIGINT;
  DECLARE VCONV_ID BIGINT;
  DECLARE OK TINYINT;
  DECLARE VNOMEESPEC,VNOMEMED VARCHAR(100);

  DECLARE CURS CURSOR FOR  SELECT DIA,COALESCE(A.DURACAO,30) AS DURACAO, A.HINI, A.HFIM, A.STAFF_ID,B.NOME AS NOMESTAFF, A.ESPEC_ID,C.NOME AS NOMEESPEC 
    FROM STAFF_ESCALA A  
     LEFT JOIN STAFF B ON B.ID=A.STAFF_ID 
    LEFT JOIN ESPECIALIDADES C ON C.ID=A.ESPEC_ID 
    WHERE A.DIA=DIA;
  -- DECLARE CURS CURSOR FOR  SELECT HINI, HFIM FROM STAFF_ESCALA;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET BDONE = 1;

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TBLRESULTS;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TBLRESULTS  (
    DATA_AG DATE,
     DIA TINYINT,
    HORA TIME,
    MED_ID BIGINT,
    NOME_MED VARCHAR(100),
    ESPEC_ID BIGINT,
    NOME_ESPEC VARCHAR(100)
  );



  SET DIA=DAYOFWEEK(DATAREF);
  OPEN CURS;

  SET BDONE = 0;
  REPEAT
    SET OK=TRUE;

     FETCH CURS INTO VDIA,VDURACAO,VHORAI,VHORAF,VMED_ID,VNOMEMED,VESPEC_ID,VNOMEESPEC;
    IF (MED IS NOT NULL) THEN
     SET OK=IF(MED=VMED_ID,TRUE,FALSE) ;

    END IF;
    IF (ESPEC IS NOT NULL) THEN
     SET OK=OK AND IF(ESPEC=VESPEC_ID,TRUE,FALSE) ;

    END IF;
    IF (CONVE IS NOT NULL) THEN
      -- SET @EOK=(SELECT 1 FROM STAFF_CONVENIOS A WHERE A.CONV_ID=CONVE AND A.STAFF_ID=MED LIMIT 1);
      SELECT 1 INTO @EOK FROM STAFF_CONVENIOS A WHERE A.CONV_ID=CONVE AND A.STAFF_ID=MED LIMIT 1;
      SET BTEMP=IF(@EOK IS NULL,TRUE,FALSE);
      SET OK= OK AND BTEMP ;
    END IF;

    IF (OK) THEN
       SET VHORA=VHORAI;
       IF (VDURACAO IS NULL) THEN
           SET VDURACAO=30;
         END IF;
         WHILE (VHORA <= VHORAF) DO
             SET BOCUP=(SELECT 1 FROM AGENDA_STAFF A WHERE A.DATA_MARCADA=DATAREF AND A.HORA_MARCADA=VHORA);
             IF (BOCUP IS NULL) THEN 
               INSERT INTO TBLRESULTS VALUES (DATAREF,VDIA,VHORA,VMED_ID,VNOMEMED,VESPEC_ID,VNOMEESPEC);
             END IF;
             SET VHORA=ADDTIME(VHORA, VDURACAO * 100);
         END  WHILE;
         SET VHORA=ADDTIME(VHORA, VDURACAO * (-100));
       IF (VHORA < VHORAF) THEN
            SET VHORA=VHORAF;
             SET BOCUP=(SELECT 1 FROM AGENDA_STAFF A WHERE A.DATA_MARCADA=DATAREF AND A.HORA_MARCADA=VHORA);
             IF (BOCUP IS NULL) THEN 
            INSERT INTO TBLRESULTS VALUES (DATAREF,VDIA,VHORA,VMED_ID,VNOMEMED,VESPEC_ID,VNOMEESPEC);
            END IF;
         END IF;

    END IF;
  UNTIL BDONE END REPEAT;

  CLOSE CURS;

  SELECT A.* FROM TBLRESULTS A LEFT JOIN AGENDA_STAFF B ON B.STAFF_ID=A.MED_ID AND B.HORA_MARCADA=A.HORA AND B.DATA_MARCADA=A.DATA_AG;

END
```

//
The problem is with the lines:

```
 -- SET @EOK=(SELECT 1 FROM STAFF_CONVENIOS A WHERE A.CONV_ID=CONVE AND A.STAFF_ID=MED LIMIT 1);
      SELECT 1 INTO @EOK FROM STAFF_CONVENIOS A WHERE A.CONV_ID=CONVE AND A.STAFF_ID=MED LIMIT 1;
```

If I use "SET @EOK..." all works well.

If I use `SELECT 1 INTO @EOK..` the problem appears.

More info with data

Expected result from call p_gethorarios(7,'2017-11-20',47,21)

```
"data_ag";"dia";"hora";"med_id";"nome_med";"espec_id";"nome_espec"
"2017-11-20";"2";"08:30:00";"7";"Paulo Renato Scofano";"47";"Pediatria/Neonatologia"
"2017-11-20";"2";"09:00:00";"7";"Paulo Renato Scofano";"47";"Pediatria/Neonatologia"
"2017-11-20";"2";"09:30:00";"7";"Paulo Renato Scofano";"47";"Pediatria/Neonatologia"
"2017-11-20";"2";"10:00:00";"7";"Paulo Renato Scofano";"47";"Pediatria/Neonatologia"
"2017-11-20";"2";"08:30:00";"7";"Paulo Renato Scofano";"47";"Pediatria/Neonatologia"
"2017-11-20";"2";"09:00:00";"7";"Paulo Renato Scofano";"47";"Pediatria/Neonatologia"
"2017-11-20";"2";"09:30:00";"7";"Paulo Renato Scofano";"47";"Pediatria/Neonatologia"
"2017-11-20";"2";"10:00:00";"7";"Paulo Renato Scofano";"47";"Pediatria/Neonatologia"
```

STAFF-ESCALA TABLE

```
ID;STAFF_ID;DIA;HINI;HFIM;ESPEC_ID;DURACAO;CREATION_TIME;MODIFICATION_TIME;LAST_USER_MODIF

    25;7;2;08:00:00;10:00:00;50;;18/11/2017 21:44:02;;1
    26;7;6;08:00:00;10:00:00;50;;18/11/2017 21:55:27;;1
    27;7;4;08:00:00;10:00:00;50;;18/11/2017 21:55:27;;1
    28;7;5;08:00:00;10:00:00;50;;18/11/2017 21:56:36;;1
    35;7;3;08:00:00;10:00:00;47;;19/11/2017 19:10:29;;1
    36;7;5;08:00:00;10:00:00;47;;19/11/2017 19:10:29;;1
    38;7;2;08:00:00;10:00:00;47;;19/11/2017 19:10:29;;1
```

Comment: This variable `DIA` doesn't have any `value` in here.. Perhaps you should include this as your parameter? That is why it returns nothing.

Comment: This is not a problem. I can set DIA to 1,2 3, etc. and the problem continues. It sems when I use "Select INTO..." the stored proc is returning from calling client and doesn´t executes the next codes. If I use SET VDATEI=(SELECT A>DATAE......) all works well. They are the same sql structure.

Comment: I have used firebird and it´s too easy to do it. But I have no experience with mysql. Why "select into.." make  the SP returns immediately?

Comment: Your are using this `WHERE A.DIA=DIA;` but i didn't see any related value why? DIA must be a parameter i guess.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is a fairly meaningless concept

Comment: The real SP is more complex. I create a simple snippet to show the problem. I will  put the real SP code in the question.

Comment: You have to include more options here.. Not to guess us. It's your problem not us. we are just only helping as we can. But it seems like `SELECT DIA,COALESCE(A.DURACAO,30) AS DURACAO, A.HINI   FROM STAFF_ESCALA A  
    WHERE A.DIA=DIA;` is a `crap`

Comment: @reds Sorry. I know it is my problem. But, I thought it was a common problem the use of "select into " in Stored Procedures with mysql.

Comment: I think much better to include a sample data here and your expected result. It might be solve your problem.

Comment: Is it possible the SELECT INTO is triggering the NOT FOUND condition? (I'm not sure it is actually limited to cursors.) ...actually, if I recall my MySql correctly; once you resolve this, your proc may end up with issues due to it executing the loop one more time even after the cursor has "ended".

Comment: @Uueerdo Yes, it is possible. Any suggestion to catch it?

Comment: It would probably be easier if you restructure your iteration to fetch before entering the loop, and fetch again at end (within) the loop, and check at the start of the loop (rather than a do-while style); you can then reset BDONE before each fetch to eliminate false finishes.

Comment: I have posted the data from table and the expected data

Comment: @Uueerdo Good sugestion. Thank you.

Comment: @Uueerdo You are correct. The problem was bDone being changed to 0 after the "Select into  ..". I just did: "SET #tDone=bDone;
   select 1 into #eok from STAFF_CONVENIOS A where A.conv_id=conve and A.staff_id=med limit 1;
   if (bDone and !#tDone) then set bDone=0; end if;" and the problem was solved. Thank  you very much. PS: I used # instead of user variable simbol to avoid problem  when posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to use user/session variables (the @xyz kind). The documentation does not explicitly state such, but it only shows examples with them.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

---

If it is an issue with the NOT FOUND handler getting triggered from something other than the cursor, you could try structuring your code something like this (very pseudocode):

```
FETCH     
WHILE( NOT DONE )
BEGIN
   DO STUFF
   SET DONE = FALSE
   FETCH
END
```

Comment: I changed all to session user but no look

Comment: The problem is with "SELECT A.DATEI, A.DIAI,A.HORAI  INTO VDATEI, VD.....".  When I use it, the  result set is empty

Comment: `SELECT A.DATEI, A.DIAI,A.HORAI INTO VDATEI, VD.....` does not use user/session variables, and example of such variables would be `SELECT 1 INTO @a`

Comment: Yes, I know. I did a test and changed it to user variable using @. The problem continues.

Comment: It seems if I use "select into ....."  the stored proc returns immediatelly and doesn´t executes the next statements.. Is there a workaround to avoid it?